# Data Driven Security in SSAS for hierarchy

Tags: sql, security, ssas, cube

I want to Implement Data Driven Security for Hierarchy in SSAS without using role.

I have table like : Dimcompany, DimProduct, DimUser
Table Name:   DimCompany

### CompnayId      CompanyName

1               XYZ
2               ABC

Table Name : DimProduct

### Productid      Productname         CompanyId

1              xyx220192            1
2              xyz220193            1
3              xyz767002            1
4              abc090921            2
4              abc990099            2
4              abc202028            2

Table Name : DimUser

### UserId         UserAccount

1              Domain\User1
2              Domain\user2

Now i want to create a Data driven security in SSAS by giving access of XYZ company to User1. So that in case, in future if any new matterid insert to XYZ company, User1 will get automatically access to that matterId. I want to create a hierarchy in such way that, i want to give Company access to particular user so that user can have access to its respected matterid.

i have created bridge table. but user not able to access respected matterid of given company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do so without roles, you need to create at least one role per company, and assign all users of that company to that role, so that users can be restricted to see data only for the company they belongs.

Answer (score 0):

When you said you want security without a role, did you mean without lots of hardcoded roles?

I would take this approach of dynamic dimension security:
http://hccmsbi.blogspot.com/2007/08/implementing-user-specific-security-in.html